# How do I log access to folders in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I'd like to share a folder with someone outside of my domain and have a log of when they download any content from that folder. Is this something that could be done with a Google Apps script?

E.g. I share a Google Drive folder that contains a proposal and all related CAD files. I would like to know when the person I share the files with actually downloads them.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished through the Google Apps Control Panel if you are an administrator (or if you have administrator access to the Reports page in Google Apps).

Just go to the Cpanel > Reports > Drive and Docs, edit the filter and add the "actor email" (the email of the user who will be receiving files), and conduct the search. Any views or edits of **documents** will be logged. Folder views are not logged.
[image]